# Is there a danger in looping through postgres query results with huge row counts?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have inherited some (PHP) code which queries a postgres table that has somewhere around 400000 rows in it.  The processing is broken up into two steps, like so:

1. Query the first 200000 rows (using "FETCH FIRST 200000 ROWS ONLY")
2. Loop through the rows one at a time and do some processing for each. (Note: the rows are NOT collected as an array.) The processing involves reading a row from (a different) table in the PG database, and writing a row to a MySQL database.
3. Next, do the *exact same query* as Step 1, but skip over the first 200000 rows (using "OFFSET 200000 ROWS") and read the remainder of the table;
4. Loop through the rows and do the *exact same* processing as in Step 2.

Furthermore, nothing is done between Steps 2 and 3.

So, it simply looks as though the programmer (whom I no longer have access to) simply decided to break the processing into two halves.  Was there any good reason for this?  Is there, for example, some buffer being filled up that I don't know about?

Here's the essential code.  The FETCH clause is changed to "OFFSET 200000 ROWS" the second time through.

```
$sql = "select [a bunch of stuff from a postgres table] FETCH FIRST 200000 ROW ONLY"
$stmt = $pgConn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $mysqlConn->beginTransaction();
    $counter = 0;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // $row is from PG database
        if (!($++counter % 1000)) {
            $mysqlConn->commit();
            $mysqlConn->beginTransaction();
        }
        $ssn = "";
        $schoolBranch = "00";
        $isir_data = "";
        
        // Get row from MySQL exportReport table based on data from the PG row:
        
        $mySqlSsn = "SELECT ssn, current_ssn from verification.exportReport where id = :studid";
        $mySqlSsnStmt = $mysqlConn->prepare($mySqlSsn, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        if ($mySqlSsnStmt->execute(array(":studid" => $row['id']))) {
            if($row_ssn = $mySqlSsnStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
                $ssn = $row_ssn['ssn'];
                $currentSsn = $row_ssn['current_ssn'];
            }
        } 
        $enc_key = getSchoolKey($row['school_code']);

        // If we didn't find the SSN in the mySQL row, and we have the encryption key (from PG), look for (one) ISIR rec in PG:
        
        if((empty($ssn) || $ssn=="000000000" || empty($currentSsn) || $currentSsn=="000000000")&& !empty($enc_key)){
            $sql_isir = "select isir_data from isir_rec ir where ir.student_id_fk = :sid order by creation_date desc limit 1";
            $stmt_isir = $pgConn->prepare($sql_isir, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
            if ($stmt_isir->execute(array(":sid" => $row['id']))) {
                if ($row_isir = $stmt_isir->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $isir_data = $row_isir['isir_data'];
                }
            }
            :
        [irrelevant stuff unrelated to DB]
            :
        $dob = $row['dob'];
        $email_address = $row['student_email_address'];
        $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
        $address_1 = $row['address_1'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $state = $row['state'];
        $zip = $row['zip'];
        $creation_date = $row['creation_date'];
        $student_sign_date = $row['student_sign_date'];
        $parent_sign_date = $row['parent_sign_date'];

        $mysqlInsert = "INSERT INTO verification.exportReport [a bunch of stuff calculated above]";
        $mySqlStmt = $mysqlConn->prepare($mysqlInsert, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $mySqlStmt->execute(array([...stuff...]));
    }
    $mysqlConn->commit();
}
```

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code. I'd just remove the limit and try all rows at once. If if breaks, there's your answer.

Comment: I'm wondering why the query that reads the initial table isn't also returning the associated result from the second table. Given that the initial query looks suspect, is there any filtering going on at PHP level that should be delegated to PostGres? If so, you might find you don't need to fetch 400,000 rows at all.

Comment: Yes, please show the essential parts from the PHP code. What you describe looks fishy to me.

Comment: Sounds like the original programmer had poor understanding of SQL, at least at the time. One possibility, perhaps they broke up due to insufficient memory. How long is each row?

Comment: Here's the basic code, with a bunch of irrelevant stuff stripped out.  The PG query says "FETCH FIRST 200000 ROW ONLY".  Then they repeat the whole thing over again, but they change the clause to "OFFSET 200000 ROWS".